# Font size inconsistencies between browsers

Tags: discussion, fonts, font-size, browsers

I was wondering, what is meant to be the correct font size for regular text on the SO-family sites? In Firefox (3.5) it appears as 10pt/13px but in Chrome and Opera it's bigger, about 11pt/15px I think.

Personally I prefer the slightly larger text, it fits better with SO's spacious design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I viewed this exact question in Chrome, Safari and Firefox all at the same time and found that at least the body text was identically sized in all of them. Did you leave Chrome zoomed in on the page, by chance?

(If not, might I recommend that if you prefer larger font size?)

Comment: Definitely not zoomed. I think it's just a browser inconsistency.

Comment: Wasn't aware at posting that you were on Linux; there may be an inconsistency there. On Windows, all three of the browsers I mentioned are identical.

Answer (score 3):

You're at the mercy of what the user has set up as their default fonts.

For example my copy of Chrome has the following:

- Serif Font: Times New Roman, 16
- Sans-Serif Font: Arial, 16
- Fixed-width Font: Courier New, 13

While in Firefox I have:

- Serif Font: Century, 16
- Sans-Serif Font: Arial, 16
- Fixed-width Font: Courier New, 13

I've also got the "Allow pages to choose there own fonts" option checked in Firefox.

I changed the font faces in Firefox a while ago, but didn't change the font sizes. So I'd check your setup.

Comment: My version of Chrome (4.x on Linux) doesn't have any font size settings, but as far as I can tell it's set the same as every other browser default (i.e. 16px). I think it's just a browser inconsistency with percent sizes. If the font is set to 78% instead of 80% it becomes consistent.